# Mouseless display of code editor warning/error description?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio 2010, I have a method which claims to return a value and then doesn't.

[image: Code Editor with compile error]

When I hover over the error with my mouse, a tooltip tells me that the method doesn't return a value.

I'm trying to avoid mouse dependency. How can I make the error description display in the status bar (alternatively as a tooltip) when my *keyboard cursor* is resting on the method name?

Comment: What are you using here? Stock VS? Code Rush? With Resharper, I get the error indicator at the `}`, which I find distasteful, as it is hard to see. However, when I put my cursor on the indicator, it says in the `return` statement is missing.

Comment: The screenshot displays what I experience in either stock or CR.

Answer (score 1):

Use F8/Shift F8 for displaying Next/Previous error on status bar